# Reduction of np to npc

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, polynomial-time, p-vs-np, polynomial-time-reductions

Given that $A$ is $NPC$ problem. And I need to check "if $D$ belongs to $NP$ and  $D\leq_p^\mathsf{}A$ then $D$ is $NPC$" is true or not?

**My approach:** Since $D\leq_p^\mathsf{}A$,  therefore $A$ is at least as hard as $D$, and given $A$ is $NPC$, consequently $D$ could be like easy problem $P, NP. $ And to prove $D$ is $NPC$ we need to proof $D$ is $NPH$ but I am unable to proven. Therefore $D$ can't be $NPC.$

Don't know my approach and result is right or not. If I did anything wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that $D$ could be in $P$ does not disprove "$D$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete" since it could be the case that $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$.

However the claim is false regardless of the  $\mathsf{P}$ vs  $\mathsf{NP}$ matter. Simply pick $D=\emptyset$ and $A$ as any $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem. Clearly $D$ cannot be $\mathsf{NP}$-complete  since it is not $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.
To see that $D$ is not  $\mathsf{NP}$-hard notice that, given any language $B \in\mathsf{NP} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$, it is false  that $B \le_p D$.

Comment: you mean if any two problem exists in NP, the reduction between them isn't not possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It is false that, given any two problems $A,B \in \mathsf{NP}$, you have $A \le_p B$. I don't know if this answers your question or how this relates to my answer.

Comment: my approach is right?